# setTimeout only executes once

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable

Why is the setTimeout only being called once?

```
repeatSubscriber = function(observer) {
        observer.next('first');
        (function() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next('repeating timed resp');
            }, 3000);
        }());
    };
```

**Prints:**

```
first
repeating timed resp
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is always useful.

Comment: setTimeout is only there to run once. you need to setInterval. Answer by Luca should fix your issue and please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval for details on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is only supposed to trigger once - what you need is `setInterval()`.

Comment: I tried setInterval before and it didn't work.. but now its working

Answer (score 2):

Because it should:

> setTimeout() sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code **once** after the timer expires.

[More at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

What you are looking for is `setInterval()`

```js
repeatSubscriber = function(observer) {
        observer.next('first');
        (function() {
            setInterval(() => {
                observer.next('repeating timed resp');
            }, 3000);
        }());
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it worked like this its in the function nature,

If you need repeated call you need `setInterval` function